# How to change state of SwiftUI Toggle externally

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to change the state of a Toggle from outside the view. I've tried ObservableObject and EnvironmentObject, but the toggle is expecting a Binding (@State).

- I need to execute a callback when the user taps the toggle
- I need to change the state of the toggle programmatically w/o executing the callback.
- I am using a shared model for this and other views, ideally I'd like to be able to use that for an 'enabled' Bool to take the place of the State var isOn.

This code does let me execute the callback via the extension, but I cannot figure out how to change the State variable isOn externally, and if I was able to, I'm guessing my callback would be executed, which I don't want to happen.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ControlView: View {
    var title: String
    var panel: Int
    var callback: ()-> Void
    @State public var isOn = false // toggle state
    @EnvironmentObject var state: MainViewModel

    //@ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
             
            // -- Header
            HStack() {
                Text(" ")
                Image(self.state.panelIcon(panel: panel)).resizable().frame(width: 13.0, height: 13.0)
                Text(title)
                Spacer()
            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0))
            .background(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9))
            
            // -- Switch

            Toggle(isOn: $isOn.didSet { (state) in
                // Activate ARC
                callback()
            }) {
                Text("Enable ARC")
            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 12, bottom: 10, trailing: 12))

        }.overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8), lineWidth: 1.25)
        ).background(Color.white)
    }
}

extension Binding {
    func didSet(execute: @escaping (Value) -> Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: { self.wrappedValue },
            set: {
                self.wrappedValue = $0
                execute($0)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your deployment target iOS version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track by creating a custom `Binding` with a `set` function that performs your side effect. But instead of using a `State`, create a custom `Binding` that directly modifies the `enabled` property of your `ObservableObject`. Example:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var enabled: Bool = false
    @Published var sideEffectCount: Int = 0
}

struct RootView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MyModel

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Side effect count: \(model.sideEffectCount)")

            Button("Set to false programmatically") {
                model.enabled = false
            }

            Button("Set to true programmatically") {
                model.enabled = true
            }

            Toggle("Toggle without side effect", isOn: $model.enabled)

            Toggle("Toggle WITH side effect", isOn: Binding(
                get: { model.enabled },
                set: { newValue in
                    withAnimation {
                        if newValue {
                            model.sideEffectCount += 1
                        }
                        model.enabled = newValue
                    }
                }
            ))
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    RootView()
        .environmentObject(MyModel())
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the problem (maybe the reason someone down voted it). You have two toggles, with and without an action. I can already do that - the default behavior without the custom bindind is no action. With a binding we can call an action. You show setting model.enabled being set as a result of the the toggle becoming ON. But won't this will happen whether set manually by the user or if set programmatically? I need a way to set model.enabled to false programmatically, have the toggle state update, but NOT call the action.

Comment: If you set `model.enabled`directly, or through a default `Binding`, it will not perform the side effect. It will only perform the side effect if you set the `wrappedValue` property of the custom `Binding`. That is what my code demonstrates. Clicking the “Toggle without side effect” control is exactly the same as setting `model.enabled` programmatically. It doesn't invoke the `set` function of the custom `Binding`.

Comment: I have updated my code to include buttons that set `model.enabled` “programmatically” so you can test for yourself that doing so does not trigger the side effect of the custom `Binding`.

Comment: Yes, I just verified this is working as you describe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) to trigger a side effect as the result of a value changing, such as a Binding. e.g.

```
.onChange(of:isOn) { [isOn] newValue in 
     if newValue {
         model.sideEffectCount += 1
     }
     model.enabled = newValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not fit all needs, but if you want a dead simple way to externally change a toggle, i.e.:

```
Toggle("Gradient Button Control", isOn: $buttonDisabled)
            .toggleStyle(.switch)
```

you can just change the isOn var value:

```
//set toggle to on
self.buttonDisabled = true
//set toggle to off
self.buttonDisabled = false
```

it's not perfect, there's no smooth animation, so it's a bit of a brute force method, but it is very simple.